# Compiling code containing dynamic parallelism fails

Tags: c++, cuda, parallel-processing, dynamic-execution

I am doing dynamic parallelism programming using CUDA 5.5 and an NVDIA GeForce GTX 780 whose compute capability is 3.5. I am calling a kernel function inside a kernel function but it is giving me an error:

> error : calling a __global__ function("kernel_6") from a __global__ function("kernel_5") is only allowed on the compute_35 architecture or above

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12):

You can do something like this

```
nvcc -arch=sm_35 -rdc=true simple1.cu -o simple1 -lcudadevrt
```

or

If you have 2 files simple1.cu and test.c then you can do something as below. This is called seperate compilation.

```
nvcc -arch=sm_35 -dc simple1.cu 
nvcc -arch=sm_35 -dlink simple1.o -o link.o -lcudadevrt
g++ -c test.c 
g++ link.o simple1.o test.o -o simple -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64/ -lcudart
```

The same is explained in the [cuda programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#toolkit-support-for-dynamic-parallelism.dita)

Comment: Hi thanks for reply
I am doing that but getting this error
fatal error : nvcc supports '--relocatable-device-code=true (-rdc=true)', '--device-c (-dc)', and '--device-link (-dlink)' only when targeting sm_20 or higher

Comment: Could you please attach what exactly you are doing ? simple program and the command you are running ? Because I just tried the above command for a simple program [here](http://pastebin.com/3Z2aGa4F)

Comment: Hi sir i am doing the same this ..calling a kernel function inside another kernel function .I have 2 files named sample.cpp and cuda.cu.
Please elaborate where should i add this
nvcc -arch=sm_35 -rdc=true simple1.cu -o simple1 -lcudadevrt

Comment: @user2865500 Are you using linux or windows?

Comment: I am using windows 7 .visual studio 2010 CUDA 5.5

Comment: @user2865500 Ok, now I understand. Have a look at my answer below. I hope it will solve your problem when using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Sorry I dont use windows. Look at @JackOLantern's answer. Please be specific from next time onwards. So you can get the correct answer.

Answer (score 7):

From Visual Studio 2010:

```
1) View -> Property Pages
2) Configuration Properties -> CUDA C/C++ -> Common -> Generate Relocatable Device Code -> Yes (-rdc=true)
3) Configuration Properties -> CUDA C/C++ -> Device -> Code Generation -> compute_35,sm_35
4) Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies -> cudadevrt.lib
```

Comment: I am very thankful for your help ..I have done this now i am getting this error.please donot be irretate...
nvcc : fatal error : nvcc supports '--relocatable-device-code=true (-rdc=true)', '--device-c (-dc)', and '--device-link (-dlink)' only when targeting sm_20 or higher

Comment: Make sure you have correctly accomplished step 3. Are you able to successfully compile the cdpLUDecomposition CUDA example? It uses dynamic parallelism to calculate LU decomposition.

Comment: Yes sir. i build cdpLUDeomposition CUDA example. It doesnot give any error. But Gives me this  Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

I have done all steps successfully.

Comment: @user2865500 I'm not sure what to suggest else. Are you re-building your solution or simply building it?

Answer (score 4):

You need to let nvcc generate CC 3.5 code for your device. This can be done by adding this option to nvcc command line.

```
 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35
```

You may find the CUDA samples on dynamic parallelism for more detail. They contain both command line options and project settings for all supported OS.

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simple-quicksort--cuda-dynamic-parallelism-

Comment: To use dynamic parallelism `--relocatable-device-code=true` or short `-rdc` is also needed. Also to prevent further errors don'T forget to link against cudadevrt library.